# Reset number to 1 if number is over than 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

`num` is a variable which is dynamically changed within 1 to 9.

I must update the value in HTML for example let say the `num` is 6,

i need to set 1st field as 6, second field as 7, third field as 8 and so on

in simple version, **6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5**

```
$("#one").text(num);
....
$("#nine").text(num+8);
```

EDIT: Sorry for confusion

```
$("#one").text(num);
$("#two").text(num+1);
....
$("#nine").text(num+8);
```

so for example, the value on `$("#nine")` is 6+8 = 14, whereas it should be 5

Comment: Your question title does not match your question.  Do you want to reset to 1, or to n%10?

Comment: `num + 8` is 14 not 15. your question is confusing.

Comment: "*Reset number to 1, if number is **over than** 9*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the modulus operator, `%`

In this case, something like:

```
$("#nine").text(1+num%9);
```

Comment: hi, may i know why you added num+5 ?

Comment: Just replicating your example. Took it out, now it assumes you've set `num` to whatever you're mod'ing against already.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 6;
$("#one") .text(((num + (-1)) % 9)) + 1);
$("#two") .text(((num + 0 ) % 9) + 1);
.
.
.
$("#nine").text(((num + 7) % 9)) + 1);
```

Comment: thank you so much for solution but i already marked the answer. sorry!